# Validate max integer in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read a int from stdin but I want to validate if the user exceeds the int max value. How can I do it?

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

scanf reads the decimal input and stores in the int, causing overflow. How can I check and avoid this?

Answer (score 17):

The only way to convert a string representation of a number to the actual value and to watch for overflow is to use functions from `strto..` group. In your case you need to read in a string representation of the number and then convert it using `strtol` function.

Beware of responses that suggest using `atoi` or `sscanf` to perform the final conversion. None of these functions protect from overflow.

Comment: Can you show a complete example on how to convert to a long and check the "overflow" error?

Comment: There's not much to show. In case of overflow `strtol` sets `errno` to `ERANGE`. Just check the value of `errno` to catch overflow.

Comment: And that is Ansi C compatible (C89)?

Comment: Yes, this is now `strtol` (and the rest of `strto...` functions) is described in C89/90.

Comment: The function `strtol` will check whether the range fits within a `long`. However, OP is asking about the range of an `int`. Therefore, after performing the range check for `long`, you must additionally compare the converted value with [`INT_MIN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits#Limits_of_integer_types) and `INT_MAX`, as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to set max digits to parse.

For example:

```
  int n;
  scanf("%5d", &n); // read at most 5 digits
  printf("%i\n", n);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [§7.21.6.2 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10), if the result of a conversion performed by the function `scanf` cannot be represented, then the behavior is undefined. Therefore, this function cannot be reliably used for the purpose of input validation.

However, when converting a string to an integer using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), if a range error occurs, the behavior is well-defined. In this case `errno` will be set to `ERANGE`. This will tell you if the number the user entered is out of range of a `long`. If you want to determine whether it is out of range of an `int`, then you must additionally verify that the number is larger than or equal to [`INT_MIN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits#Limits_of_integer_types) and smaller than or equal to `INT_MAX`. Note that you must `#include <limits.h>` to use these constants.

Therefore, I recommend the following code to read a number from the user and to validate it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[1024], *p;
    long num_long;
    int  num_int;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Enter a number: " );

    //get one line of input from input stream
    if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
    //the buffer was not too small)
    if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to convert string to number
    errno = 0;
    num_long = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
    if ( p == buffer )
    {
        printf( "Error converting string to number\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //make sure that no range error occurred
    if ( errno == ERANGE || num_long < INT_MIN || num_long > INT_MAX )
    {
        printf( "Range error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //range is ok, so we can convert to int
    num_int = (int)num_long;

    //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
    //so that input such as "6sdfh4q" gets rejected
    for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //number was successfully converted, so we print it
    printf( "You entered the following valid number: %d\n", num_int );
}
```

Example output of this program when entering a valid number:

```
Enter a number: 65
You entered the following valid number: 65
```

Example output of this program when entering invalid input:

```
Enter a number: 6sdfh4q
Unexpected input encountered!
```

Example output of this program when entering out of range input:

```
Enter a number: 3000000000
Range error!
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods come to mind.

The first is useful if you know the input is integer-like only input, but suffers from "slightly" exceeding integer range:

```
long x;
if (1 != scanf("%ld", &x))
         error "not a number or other i/o error"
else
if (x < -MAXINT ||  x > MAXINT)
        error "exceeds integer range"
else    printf "it is an integer";
```

This has a lot of dependency on the compiler and platform.  Note that the C language guarantees only that `long` is greater than *or equal* to the size of `int`.  If this is run on a platform where `long` and `int` are the same size, it is a useless approach.

The second approach is to read the input as a string and parse straightforwardly:

```
char buf [1000];
if (1 != scanf ("%1000s", buf))
        error "i/o error";
size_t len = strspn (buf, "0123456789+-");
if (len != strlen (buf))
        error "contains invalid characters";
long  number = 0;
int   sign = 1;
for (char *bp = buf;  *bp;  ++bp)
{
          if (*bp == '-')
          {
               sign = -sign;
               continue;
          }
          if (*bp == '+')
               continue;
          number = number * 10  +  *bp - '0';
          if (number > MAXINT)
               error "number too large";
}
if (sign < 0)
         number = -number;
```

This code has several weaknesses:  it depends on `long` being larger than `int`; it allows plus and minus to appear anywhere in the string.  It could be easily extended to allow other than base ten numbers.

A possible third approach might be to input a string check the character set and use a `double` conversion to range check.

Answer (score -1):

Read it into a string and check the length, then call either `atol()` or `sscanf()` on the string to convert it into a int.

Comment: Not `atoi` and not `sscanf`. Neither of these protect from overflow. "Checking the length" cannot be used to prevent overflow for obvious reasons.

Comment: you can assume though that if the entered number is 10 digits long it isn't gong to fit into an int.

Comment: `2000000000` is 10 digits long and it fits into a 32-bit int without a problem.

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious to you why checking the length does not work, consider an environment where `INT_MAX == 2147483647`, which is 10 digits. Now `3000000000` is also 10 digits, but exceeds INT_MAX, leading to overflow.